# display all files in data frame using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, data-analysis

I am trying to create a data frame from a data set of 1000 .txt files,
then loop through the files and gets the title, Author, language, etc to form a single data frame.

```
from glob import glob

files = glob('dataset/*.txt')
files.sort()
files
```

```
for n in files:
    with open(n, 'r') as text_file:
        text = text_file.read()

    # These can be reused for each book    
    title = re.compile(r'Title: (.*)\n')
    author = re.compile(r'Author: (.*)\n')
    release_date = re.compile(r'Release Date: (.*)\s')
    language = re.compile(r'Language: (.*)\n')

    book_title = title.search(text).group(1)
#     book_author = author.search(text).group(1)
    book_language = language.search(text).group(1)
    book_release = release_date.search(text).group(1).split(' [')[0]

    books = pd.DataFrame({"Title": [book_title], "Author": [book_author], 
    "Release_Date": [book_release], "Language": [book_language]})
    
    books
```

this displays only a single data but when I use PRINT it displays all data but as separate data frames.

How do I display all these frames as one single data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work, however, it must be said, that this program will generate an error if **ANY** of the book details are not found in **ANY** of the books.

#### Code:

```
book_title, book_author, book_release, book_language = [],[],[],[]

# These can be reused for each book    
title = re.compile(r'Title: (.*)\n')
author = re.compile(r'Author: (.*)\n')
release_date = re.compile(r'Release Date: (.*)\s')
language = re.compile(r'Language: (.*)\n')

for n in files:
    with open(n, 'r') as text_file:
        text = text_file.read()

    book_title.append(title.search(text).group(1))
    book_author.append(author.search(text).group(1))
    book_language.append(language.search(text).group(1))
    book_release.append(release_date.search(text).group(1).split(' [')[0])


books = pd.DataFrame({"Title": book_title, "Author": book_author, 
    "Release_Date": book_release, "Language": book_language})
```

#### Note:

To handle issues for when you are missing data from a book you could employ this type of technique:

```
    if author.search(text) is not None:
        book_author.append(author.search(text).group(1))
    else:
        book_author.append('-')
```

Comment: ok, this throws an error is there a way I can check for unavailable data? like using a conditional statement

Comment: Yes - use an if-statement to catch when for example `title.search(text)` returns `None`.

Comment: Have updated my answer to show you how - see **note** at end